# Left and right aligned on same line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, minipage

I am currently busy typesetting my thesis in `LaTeX`, but I am stuck on something with my cover/title page. At the bottom of the page, I need to type my name and my supervisor's name.

This is a rough idea (written in Word) of the layout in which I wish to typeset my name and my supervisor's name.

[image]

However, I have no idea how I can get the left and right alignments for my name on the left and my supervisor's name on the right.

Can anybody please show me how I can go about typsetting something like this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are a couple things you could try. A simple technique is to use `\hfill`, such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\textbf{\underline{Student:}}
\hfill
\textbf{\underline{Supervisor:}} \\
Mr. Thatshisname
\hfill
Prof. Whatshisname

\end{document}
```

This will produce the following:
[image: first_way]

This does not quite reproduce the spacing for the "Supervisor" word as shown in your sample. Another approach will reproduce this better, although it's a little more involved. This uses `\hfill` along with the `minipage` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{2in}
\textbf{\underline{Student:}} \\
Mr. Thatshisname
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{1.3in}
\textbf{\underline{Supervisor:}} \\
Prof. Whatshisname
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The size of the first `minipage` does not matter too much, since `\hfill` will fill the space, but the size of the second `minipage` needs to be tweaked to get the right edge as close to the margin as possible without forcing a line break. I used the `showframe` package to make that process easier, but perhaps someone else has a more elegant solution. Here is the output:

[image: second_way]

In order to get this on the bottom of the page, you can try using the `\vfill` command. Another approach to achieving the result you're looking for is by using the `fancyhdr` package (read "fancy header"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\textbf{\underline{Student:}} \\
    Mr. Thatshisname}
\rfoot{\textbf{\underline{Supervisor:}}
    \phantom{MMMi}\\
    Prof. Whatshisname}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

This will place these words on the bottom of every page with the pagestyle `fancy`. If you want it only on the first page, then use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\begin{document}` instead of `\pagestyle{fancy}` as shown in my example. I had to redefine the `\headrulewidth` to zero so that the line did not show up at the top of the page (can someone comment on this answer if there is a "nicer" way to do this?). This solution also has the same problem as the first, where "Supervisor" is pushed all the way to the margin. However, I used the `\phantom` command to add some white space, and fiddled with the input to make it look right. Here is that output:

[image: third_way]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The 1st approach with `hfill` triggers an 'underfull hbox' alert. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 21):

```
\begin{titlepage}
    ... whatever should be here ...
         for a titlepage

\vfill\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l} 
  \underline{\textbf{Student:}}\\  Mr. Thatshisname
\end{tabular}
\hfill% move it to the right
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
   \underline{\textbf{Supervisor:}}\\ Prof. Whatshisname
\end{tabular}
\end{titlepage}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it good practice to use tabulars in LaTeX for alignment? I'm asking since in HTML for example this frowned upon. Well they have there <div>'s forf this purpose, but I'm still wondering. Tables and alignet text are to different things IMO..

Comment: tabulars (arrays) can be aligned at top `[t]`, center (default) `[c]` or the baseline `[b]`. For the current line the tabular itself is nothing else than a box.

Comment: True, but does this not soften the barrier between "meaning" and "purpose"? The tabular environment is supposed to set tables; if i start aligning my text with it my code becomes harder to read and I can never redefine the tabular environment if I want to alter the look of my tables

Comment: Feel free, to use it in your way. But I wrote more than 10,000 pages with TeX and I never had the feeling that my way of using tabulars for aligning text makes the code hard to read.

Answer (score 10):

This uses a `tabularx` table to use the whole `\linewidth` and fills the rest of the table with an (empty!) `X` column.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\headlinestyle}[1]{\large\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\namestyle}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{4cm}Xp{4cm}@{}}
\headlinestyle{Student:} & & \headlinestyle{Supervisor:} \tabularnewline[0.5ex]
\namestyle{Mr. Gumby}    & & \namestyle{Prof. Gumby} \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

I remove the underlining on purpose -- the `showframe` package can be omitted of course.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As tables or minipages are not an option to answer anymore, something a little more quirky:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={12cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\signat#1#2{%
\makebox[\widthof{#2}][l]{\vbox{%
\textbf{\underline{#1:}}\\[5pt] #2}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]\vfill 
{\parindent0pt
\signat{Student}{Mr. Thatshisname}\hfill
\signat{Supervisor}{Prof. Whatshisname}} 
\end{document}
```

Well, less quirky:

```
\def\signat#1#2{\parbox{\widthof{#2}}{\textbf{\underline{#1:}}\par #2}}
```

**Note:** Take care that the "p" of "Supervisor" make the underline lower than  in "Student". A good reason to not underline, or at least underline `\smash{#1:}`,  or `\strut #1`, or use the `soul` package.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want the supervisor name flush right? Here it is much more common to have something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the page boundaries
\begin{document}

whatever... 

\vfill
\noindent \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{%
\underline{\textbf{Student}} \\ Mr. Studentname \\ \vspace{2cm} } % 
\parbox[t]{0.45\linewidth}{%
    \underline{\textbf{Supervisor}} \\ Mr. Supervisorname}

\end{document}
```

...with the place for signing under the names and flush left with the names.

[image: Output resulting from the snippet]