# Signatures side by side

Tags: tables, koma-script

It's been a while since I last used Latex, so please bear with me.
As the title reads, I'd like to have two signature side by side (50% each) at the bottom of a medical report. This is what I currently have (apparently with *slightly* changed author names):

```
\flushleft
\newlength\jm
\settowidth{\jm}{Luke Skywalker}
\begin{tabular}{p{\jm}}\hline
\centering\footnotesize (Luke Skywalker)
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10 mm}

The force is strong in my family
\vspace{5 mm}

\flushleft
\newlength\mb
\settowidth{\mb}{Darth Vader}
\begin{tabular}{p{\mb}}\hline
\centering\footnotesize (Darth Vader)
\end{tabular}
```

And it looks like this in `scrartcl`:
[image]

How can Luke stand right next to his father (Luke left, both with underlines) ?

Comment: Empty lines start a new paragraph, which are starting on a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-copying my answer from [Left and right aligned on same line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294150/left-and-right-aligned-on-same-line/294407#294407), given that's much more suited here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the page boundaries
\begin{document}

whatever... 

\vfill  % push the rest to the bottom of the page
\noindent \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{%
\underline{\textbf{Student}} \\ Mr. Studentname \\
\vspace{2cm} } % This 2cm is the space for the signature under the names
\parbox[t]{0.45\linewidth}{%
    \underline{\textbf{Supervisor}} \\ Mr. Supervisorname}

\end{document}
```

...with the place for signing under the names and flush left with the names. You can change the contents of the `parbox`es to adjust to your taste.

[image: Output resulting from the snippet]

More to the point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the page boundaries
\begin{document}

whatever... 

\vfill  % push the rest to the bottom of the page
\noindent 
\parbox[b]{0.4\linewidth}{% size of the first signature box
    \strut 
    Signed by: \\[2cm]% This 2cm is the space for the signature under the names
    \hrule
    (Luke Skywalker)} 
\hspace{1cm} % distance between the two signature blocks 
\parbox[b]{0.4\linewidth}{% ...and the second one
    \strut 
    The force is strong in my family: \\[2cm]% This 2cm is the space for the signature under the names
    \hrule
    (Darth Vader)} 
    \par\vspace{1cm} 
\end{document}
```

You can center the name under the lines using `\centering` before them, but you'll have an "underfull hbox" warning that I am still puzzling about...

[image: Output of the signatures]

Comment: Thanks Rmano, I've added both `\centering` and some `\vspace` under the `\hrule` so that there's some air between. Works flawlessly (and I do not get any warnings)!