# How can I align a signature dotline at both left and right of a line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

[Left and right aligned on same line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294150/left-and-right-aligned-on-same-line)[image]
How can I insert a signature dot line on both left and right alignment

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but almost: [Signature/date line with fixed width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48152/82917)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Answer (score 2):

You can define a command like

```
\newcommand\signature[1]{%
  \par\vspace{8ex}\noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \makebox[15em]{\dotfill}\\
    #1
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \makebox[15em]{\dotfill}\\
    Date
  \end{tabular}
}
```

and use it like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\signature[1]{%
  \par\vspace*{8ex}\noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \makebox[15em]{\dotfill}\\
    #1
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \makebox[15em]{\dotfill}\\
    Date
  \end{tabular}
}
\usepackage{blindtext} % only needed for the dummy text, remove it
\begin{document}
\blindtext % generates the dummy text, remove it
% Put the text to be signed here.

\signature{Mr~Joe Miller\\Seminar Supervisor}
\signature{Ms~Amy Smith\\Head of Department}
\signature{Ms~Betty Taylor\\External Examiner}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, I think this will do it

Comment: But, please how can I remove the additional text at the top

Comment: @chukwujohn Remove `\blindtext` and `\usepackage{blindtext}`, they are there for demo purposes only.

Comment: Is there a way the dummy text can be removed?

Comment: @ChukwuJohn Remove the lines `\blindtext` and `\usepackage{blindtext}`. Replace `\blindtext` by the text that has to be signed.

Comment: Thanks to you guys, problem solved .